# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: botframework

> An error has occurred. 
>   Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>   
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.<>c__3`1.<ResumeAsync>b__3_0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringDialogTask`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializingDialogTask.d__4`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LocalizedDialogTask.d__2`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUserTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUserTask.d__5`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogPostToBot.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__5`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.<ResumeAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() at
>   BotApplication.Controllers.OAuthCallbackController.d__0.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\BotApplication\BotApplication\Controllers\OAuthCallbackController.cs:line
>   55 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

This is happening when i'm trying to resume a conversation after user authentication.

I call authentication this way :

In my first dialog :

```
  var message = context.MakeMessage();
    await context.Forward(new SecondDialog(), HandleOptions, message, CancellationToken.None);
```

Then in my SecondDialog have this :

```
 var message = await argument;
                    MyStaticModel.toId = message.From.Id;
                    MyStaticModel.toName = message.From.Name;
                    MyStaticModel.fromId = message.Recipient.Id;
                    MyStaticModel.fromName = message.Recipient.Name;
                    MyStaticModel.serviceUrl = message.ServiceUrl;
                    MyStaticModel.channelId = message.ChannelId;
                    MyStaticModel.conversationId = message.Conversation.Id;
                    await context.Forward(new SimpleFacebookAuthDialog(message), ResumeAfterLogIn, message, CancellationToken.None);
```

In my Facebook Dialog i make resumption cookie this way :

```
 public SimpleFacebookAuthDialog(IMessageActivity msg)
        {
            ResumptionCookie = new ResumptionCookie(msg);
        }
```

And when user authenticate i handle authentication :

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> OAuthCallback([FromUri] string userId, [FromUri] string botId, [FromUri] string conversationId, [FromUri] string channelId, [FromUri] string serviceUrl, [FromUri] string locale, [FromUri] string code, [FromUri] string state, CancellationToken token)
        {
            //Get the resumption cookie
            Address address = new Address
                (
                    // purposefully using named arguments because these all have the same type
                    botId: FacebookHelpers.TokenDecoder(botId),
                    channelId: channelId, 
                    userId: FacebookHelpers.TokenDecoder(userId),
                    conversationId: FacebookHelpers.TokenDecoder(conversationId),
                    serviceUrl: FacebookHelpers.TokenDecoder(serviceUrl)

                );
            //var resumptionCookie = new ResumptionCookie(FacebookHelpers.TokenDecoder(userId), FacebookHelpers.TokenDecoder(botId), FacebookHelpers.TokenDecoder(conversationId), channelId, FacebookHelpers.TokenDecoder(serviceUrl), locale: locale);
            var resumptionCookie = new ResumptionCookie(address, userName: null, isGroup: false, locale: locale);

            // Exchange the Facebook Auth code with Access token
            var accessToken = await FacebookHelpers.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(resumptionCookie, code, SimpleFacebookAuthDialog.FacebookOauthCallback.ToString());

            // Create the message that is send to conversation to resume the login flow
            var msg = resumptionCookie.GetMessage();
            msg.Text = $"token:{accessToken.AccessToken}";

            // Resume the conversation to SimpleFacebookAuthDialog

            await Conversation.ResumeAsync(resumptionCookie, msg, CancellationToken.None);
```

It falls on the last line of code. When Resuming conversation.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when I run tests in vs 2019.
I could solve this by cleaning the solution ,closing vs and deleting temp files anf re launching vs-2019.
I followed the link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/875545/xunit-test-net-core-project-with-vs-2019-is-throwi.html

Answer (score 0):

I fix this guys. 
I don't know what the real reason is, but when i used to await for argument and store it as a message, later, parameters were wrong in resumption cookie.

Now, i cast argument as activity :

```
 var message = (Activity)context.Activity;
```

And it works properly.

Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when attempting to display adaptive cards. It turned out I had added the json files to the solution as content and not as embedded resources. After switching them to be embedded resources they displayed fine.